# Read Data From System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]

Tags: c#

I'm struggling to read data out of an IDictionary and would really appreciate some help. I've pulled out other data I need when it was just an object array, but I've got a KeyValuePair to deal with now. When I try and cast it as a KeyValuePair, I get an InvalidCastException so I did this to try and find the type:

```
var test = plist["CFBundleIcons"];
MessageBox.Show(test.GetType().ToString());
```

Which returned *System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Object,System.Object]*. My first question is what does the 2 mean? I've used dictionaries in the past and have never seen this before.

If it helps understand my main problem further, I've attached a screenshot of the locals view below - I'm trying to read the icon names. Thanks in advance.

[image: Locals view]

Comment: 2 is the count of generic arguments in Dictionary class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just how .NET encodes a name of a generic type with two type parameters. `plist["CFBundleIcons"]` is a `Dictionary<object, object>`. So instead of casting it to `KeyValuePair`, you should cast it to the correct type.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've changed the cast and it's finally working again.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the CLR encodes generic type names.  `` `2 `` indicates the number of type parameters in the type.

In C# terms, this is `Dictionary<object, object>`.